# jQuery custom extension throws not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to run this function

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.urlHash = function()
    {
        return document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

like so `$.urlHash()` I get an error in Google Chrome console saying `urlHash() is not a function`.

From what I could see (by Googling), the extension is written correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are accessing the method as a static method of jQuery object

```
(function ($) {
    $.urlHash = function () {
        return document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#') + 1);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

When you add the property to `$.fn` it is added to the jQuery object's prototype object, so you need to use an instance of jQuery object to access it

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `fn`, which is used on objects.

```
(function ($) {
    $.urlHash = function (){
        return document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#') + 1);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to extend the jQuery object using the `fn.extend` function, and not directly ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/)).

In your case however, you're not interested in extending the jQuery object (where a usage might look like `$('selector').extendedFunction()`) but rather declare a contextless function. You're decision to attach that function to the "jQuery namespace" ([$ vs $()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/dollar-object-vs-function/)) is valid, though odd. You could just as well have decided to extend any other "namespace" or simply extend the global namespace.